# Why can't I set display to none in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a javascript function called showOrHide that toggles the display state of a table row element. The code looks something like this:

```
function showOrHide(myId)
{
    document.getElementById(myId).style.display = (document.getElementById(myId).style.display=="none" ? "table-row" : "none") 
}
```

This works correctly in Firefox and Chrome... but for some reason, when trying to collapse/hide the row in IE8, it crashes. I've tried explicitly running the code -

```
document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "table-row";
```

executes correctly; but

```
document.getElementById(myId).style.display = "none";
```

crashes the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error message from IE?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - the page sort of flickers, and I get a little notification popup - "This tab has been recovered. A problem with this webpage caused Internet Explorer to close and reopen this tab."

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be able to get aroud the problem by setting the height to 0 instead.

Comment: @froadie: Wow, it's actually crashing the tab.  Impressive! :)  Can you post a link to the page or post the code, if it's not huge?  That will help diagnosis.

Comment: It appears to work fine here http://www.jsfiddle.net/3JPs5/ maybe another bit of code is buggering it up eh?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - the page is protected (requires a login) and the code is kind of big... what parts of the code could be relevant? I can post parts of it...

Comment: Before you go posting any code, are you able to run it through an validator?  You should be able to paste the rendered code if it's not available to access directly to the validator.  If the HTML has serious problems, the JavaScript may be correct but cause the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still haven't discovered what the bug is... We gave up in the end and used jQuery instead.